# Drawing an empty chess board with good portability?

Tags: pdftex

I would like to make chess board, which will be empty.
I would like that it can be compiled using PDFLATEX on most tex/texlive/...
I would like that the lines for black squares are sort of lines (diagonal), as in the example.

The usual starting code is this one:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm]
    \foreach \x in {0,...,7} \foreach \y in {0,...,7}
    {
        \pgfmathparse{mod(\x+\y,2) ? "black" : "white"}
        \edef\colour{\pgfmathresult}
        \path[fill=\colour] (\x,\y) rectangle ++ (1,1);
    }
    \draw (0,0)--(0,8)--(8,8)--(8,0)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Best regards

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to google `chess latex`? I get `https://ctan.org/pkg/chess` which leads to `https://ctan.org/pkg/skak`, `https://ctan.org/pkg/chessfss` and `https://ctan.org/pkg/texmate`.

Comment: In addition, is there a specific reason that you don't accept the answers that you get in your previous questions?

Comment: Because it makes no reasons to need to install 2-4Gb Texlive for compiling basic stuffs. Any journals would refuse a complex TeX format document for manuscript. Anyhow people keep making un-compilable TeX documents, which causes lot of money waste for research.

Comment: I do not see how your comment answers my questions.  But, it's not very important. In addition, I don't understand what you are trying to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case you need uppercase labels, here is the PSTricks solution.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-.5,-.5)(8,8)
    \multips(0,0)(2,0){4}{
        \multips(0,0)(0,2){4}{
            \psset{fillstyle=vlines,linestyle=none,hatchangle=-45,hatchsep=1pt}
            \psframe(1,1)
            \psframe(1,1)(2,2)
        }
    }
    \psframe(8,8)
    \foreach \i in {0,1,...,7}{
        \rput(!\i\space .5 add -.5){\char\numexpr\i+65}
        \rput(!-.5 \i\space .5 add){\the\numexpr\i+1}
    }
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It is not working, because there is portable needs. is it possible without pstricks ?

Comment: @user98734: Everything that can be created with PSTricks, finally will be created with PSTricks. Compile it with either `xelatex` or `latex-dvips-ps2pdf` and you get a Portable Document Format (PDF) that conforms to your requirement of portability.

Comment: well, the title of the thread was with good portability, and xelatex is certainly not. :(

Comment: It is not clear at all what you mean with "portability", at least to me and I guess that's also the case with @Artificial Stupidity.

Comment: portability means that it is portable on any bare TeX environment, i.e. Miktex default, Texlive small install, ... and on any Mac, Linux and BSD,... on ultra portability. If you aren't familiar with programming, herewith a cool reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_portability

Answer (score 8):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chessboard}
\begin{document}

\chessboard[clearboard]

\end{document}
```

[image]